# Android Browser with developer tools

Tags: android, web-development, web-browser, debugging

What application should I use to bring fully fledged developer browsing experience (where I not just view a page as end user, but also discover and edit DOM tree, debug JavaScript, view network requests)?

If I search about for things like "debug browser Android", I typically get results about remote debugging using adb, i.e. things that require having some bigger device with a keyboard nearby.

Is there, on the other hand, a browser version (Chromium or Firefox) that have interface and features equivalent to desktop one (or may be touch-optimised), yet working on Android? It is clear why those features are not included by default, but I assume it should not be much of a problem to have them as a browser add-on or a separate app.

Comment: Would you mind detailing your use case? Your most pressing need is: 1) To debug webpages while on the go without a laptop, or 2) Debug a mobile website in a more realistic environment than Chrome or Firefox' mobile simulation?

Comment: Probably "1)". To remove occasional annoying elements (like a manual ad blocker), to see whether NoScript is interfering with loading some resources (using console), just to stop JavaScript and render page passive, to edit some CSS style to remove annoying font or colour. It is annoying to be locked to "consumer" mode of Web browsing - I want to have a final say of how a page behaves and override some web developer decisions.